# When refering to the object pk in the tableview i get a pk error but i still can refere to the object from the context

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views, django-tables2

I have a django app where I want to show a table of user entries and users can delete/edit entries from the table by buttons. I used django-tables2 as the library to render the table.

Tables.py

```
class PatientTable(tables.Table):

FirstName = tables.Column(linkify=("patients:patient_detail", {"pk": tables.A("pk")}))
LastName = tables.Column(linkify=("patients:patient_detail", {"pk": tables.A("pk")}))
Telephone_no = tables.Column(linkify=("patients:patient_detail", {"pk": tables.A("pk")}))

delete = TemplateColumn('<button type ="button" class ="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDelete" >Deleta</button>',extra_context={'patient': 'Patient'})

class Meta:
    model = Patient
    attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-hover'}
    exclude = ("user", "Notes", "Adress")
    template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
```

Views.py

```
def Patients_list(request):

patients = Patient.objects.all()
table = PatientTable(patients.filter(user=request.user))
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

return render(request, 'patients/patients_list.html',{
'table' : table,
'patients':patients,
})
```

here in the views I defined the patients in the context to be callable in the template,It's callable but i can't call the patients.pk, it always return a value error.

Template

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

{% block content %}

<div id="content">

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <h1> Patients list: </h1>
    <br>

    <a href="{%url 'patients:patient_create'%}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Add Patient</a>
    <br>
    <br>

    {% render_table table %}

    {% else %}

      <h2>please login</h2>

    {% endif %}

</div>

 <div class="modal fade" id="modalDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalDelete"
  aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Delete patient!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this patient?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
           <form method="POST" action="{% url 'patients:patient_delete' pk=patients.pk %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="btn btn-danger" value="Yes" type="submit" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                       </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  {% endblock %}
```

in this template I get this error :

```
Reverse for 'patient_delete' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['patients/delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
```

I tried

```
Patients.pk
pk
```

but it didn't work,in the template i tried making a for loop(after deleting the form ofc) to show each patient First name in a paragraph tag and it worked I also tried making a different template having for the delete form and it worked but now i want to make the delete form in a modal callable by the button.

My model:

```
# Patient model each patient is uniquely identified by his doctor/user
class Patient(models.Model):
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    Adress = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    Telephone_no = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='patients')
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    # Age = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank = True ,null = True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    Notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.FirstName) + " " + str(self.LastName)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('patient_detail', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

There's another related model to this one has a patient field as a ForiegnKey btw.

I tried changing the view into this as user from recommended but it's the same problem

the new view:

```
def Patients_list(request):

patients = Patient.objects.filter(user=request.user)
table = PatientTable(patients)
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

return render(request, 'patients/patients_list.html',{
'table' : table,
'patients':patients,
})
```

The suggestion was that I couldn't get the pk from `Patient.objects.all()` and I needed to change it to a form with get but get didn't work so i used filter.

I think if i changed it to a CBV it should work but I don't really know how to make the queryset should i make it with defining it just like the normal CBV.

I've been stuck on this for 10 days now asking on many forums/sites so I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve what i wanted is to render the table manually in the template by making a for loop and iterate through all objects.